# Who has the best single-target heal in Overwatch? (numbers-wise)

Tags: overwatch

On the internet, I have seen various posts talking about how Mercy has the best single-target heal, or how Ana has the best single-target heal, et cetera. So, I was wondering, numbers-wise, who has the best single-target heal in the game (within the support category)? When I say this, I mean if Ana fires her rifle at the maximum speed possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My math might be wrong, BUT:

According to the [wiki](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Ana?version=f750027f0df0baaaa8875830eca342f0), Ana fires 1.2 rounds per second, which is 90 HPS.
She fires her 10 rounds in 8.3 seconds.
When we add the reload time of 1.5 we get that she can heal for 750 (75 heal * 10 rounds) in 9.8 seconds. Which is 76.5 (~75) heal. This of course if in a perfect, BUT plausible world.

Then we have the added option of going up to 150 HPS thanks to her Biotic Grenade (not counting the instant 100 Heal the grenade does)

Mercy comes in second with 60 Heal Per Second

Lucio does 12.5 (36 when amping up), Zen does 30 hp heal per second.

The very very tricky part here is consistency. Mercy is 100% consistent, if you are in range, and she's clicking her Mouse1, heal comes in. Ana has to be actually a good shooter to heal you, even though the friendly shot is rather forgiving.

But in a perfect scenario Ana heals the most.

it's worth pointing out that you aren't asking for the best support so technically RoadHog is the right answer to your question, as he does 300 self heal over a second ...

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add that

Comment: You're ignoring reload times and cooldowns.

Comment: @Иво Недев I have seen this video, just wondering how much one support hero could heal per second

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Yet I've mention it, the question doesn't specifically ask for sustained heal over a minute or whatever, but is asking for numbers alone

Comment: But as it stands the answer is not complete

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I've crunched some numbers to reflect reload time.